# Multiple bindings expressions in one statement

Tags: wpf

Does WPF support multiple binding expressions in one statement?
Something along the lines of the following:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OrderID} shipped on {Binding Path=OrderDate}"/>
```

I'm guessing that it does but I think I just don't have the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a MultiBinding with the StringFormat feature. Look at the [docs for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} shipped on {1:D}">
      <Binding Path="OrderID" />
      <Binding Path="OrderDate"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

To add support for forrmating specific sections of the textblock, [use Inlines like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines(v=VS.95).aspx).

```
<Textblock>
   <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding OrderID}"/>
   <Run Text="shipped on "/>
   <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding OrderDate}"/>
</Textblock>
```

Comment: Awesome! Just 1 question. Is there a way to apply styles to parts of the text, such as making the OrderID and Date Bold when using MultiBinding or would I need to split up the parts into multiple TextBlocks

Comment: In order to do what you want use the Inlines initialization. I've updated the response to show.